# How to populate psychopy.event.getKeys()?

Tags: python, psychopy

Hitting apostrophe is not doing anything. start_scan is just a textStim.

```
while True:
    print event.getKeys()
    start_scan.draw()
    win.flip()
    if "'" in event.getKeys():
        break
    event.clearEvents()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because `event.getKeys()` returns apostrophe as the string `'apostrophe'`. To see that do

```py
from psychopy import visual, event
win = visual.Window()
while True:
    response = event.getKeys()
    if response:
        print response  # check what the key was
        if 'apostrophe' in response:
            break
```

The reason you don't see that printed is that each call to `event.getKeys()` clears the event buffer. Similarly of course for `event.clearEvents()`. Since your script will spend like 99.9% of it's time hanging at `win.flip()` it is very unlikely that the key press happened just prior to your `print event.getKeys()`, thus it never prints how the event module represents the keys you pressed.

So this is something to look out for. The event module doesn't always represent keys by the characters they produce. However,`psychopy.iohub` module does just that. So e.g. something like SHIFT+r becomes "R". It does require a few more lines of code to get running, though. See the [documentation](http://www.psychopy.org/api/iohub/device/keyboard.html) and the demo under Coder --> demos --> iohub --> keyboard.

Comment: This worked! Thank you. Our EPI scan sent the apostrophes down the wire and triggered the experiment. Thanks.